# flash as3 how to prevent an item from being added to an array if it already exists in the array

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3

I know how to remove duplicates from an array, but what I'm trying to do is prevent an item from ever being added to an array in the first place if it already exists. I'm pulling in data from an xml feed in a loop, and I thought that searching for that values index would work, but no matter what, the index is always -1. Here's my code:

```
var yearArr:Array = new Array();

for (var i=0;i<numCovers;i++){
  var coverRef = xmlObj.cover[i];
  var coverClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
  coverClip.year = coverRef.@year;
  if (yearArr.indexOf(coverClip.year === -1)){
    yearArr.push (coverClip.year);
  }
}
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the indexOf function, but I thought it was supposed to return -1 if a value did not exist in an array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Count the opening parentheses `(` and the closing parentheses `)` on the line with the `indexOf` function.  Notice anything odd?

Comment: That's just a mistype - the valid code pushes the year to the array no matter what. I've edited the code above though, good catch.

Comment: It's weird - my code above actually works if you substitute an actual number instead of the variable reference...

Comment: yearArr.indexOf(coverClip.year === -1) LOL wonder if he got it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
var yearArr:Array = new Array();

for (var i=0;i<numCovers;i++){
  var coverRef = xmlObj.cover[i];
  var coverClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
  coverYear = coverRef.@year;
  addCoverYear(coverYear);
}

function addCoverYear(coverYear:int):void {
    if (yearArr.indexOf(coverYear) == -1){
        yearArr.push(coverYear);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can reduce an array by passing everything to a dictionary, which will automatically remove redundancies.  then pass the dictionary back as a new array.

```
//Reduce Array
private function reduceArray(array:Array):Array
    {
    var dictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    for each    (var element:String in array)
                dictionary[element] = true;

    var result:Array = new Array();

    for         (var key:String in dictionary)
                result.push(key);

    dictionary = null;

    return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost fine. The problem is that an E4X property `.@year` is not a literal string (I'm not sure right now, but I believe it's an `XMLList` object). That's why the `indexOf` call will keep returning -1, because it is looking for a duplicate of that object, not a string. E4X will convert it to a string as soon as you put it somewhere where only strings can go, but until that time it is something else.

If you rewrite your code like this, it should work right away:

```
var yearArr:Array = new Array();

for each (var coverRef : XML in xmlObj.cover){
  var year : String = coverRef.@year; // force the property to be a string
  if (yearArr.indexOf(year) < 0){
    yearArr.push (year);
  }
}
```

There were also a few other optimizations you could do to your code. The `new MovieClip()` part wasn't used, not all variables were strongly typed and by using a `for each` loop, you can state much clearer what objects you're looping through.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could do, if for example, you have an array of strings.

```
var ItemList:Array = new Array();

for each(var Item:String in UseYourXMLFeed) 
 {
    if(ItemList.indexOf(Item) == -1) 
    {
        ItemList.push(Item);
    }
 }
```

---

**Edit:**

Anyways, your real answer is in the comment by Sam.

Comment: search is not a function in flash

Comment: Ohh sorry, I meant indexOf. Well I wrote it more as an algorithm for the OP, earlier.....guess that's where the word 'search' came from. Thank you for pointing out. :)